# Django Password Reset No reverse match

Tags: django

I am trying to use password reset of django

I am getting the following error after I have entered email for password reset

> django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for
>   'password_reset_confirm' not found. 'password_reset_confirm' is not a
>   valid view function or pattern name.

my urls.py include

```
path(
        "dashboard/",
        include(("ami.dashboard.urls", "dashboard"), namespace="dashboard"),
    ),
```

my dashboard/urls.py is

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
# from graphene_django.views import GraphQLView

# from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
from . import views as core_views
from .product.urls import urlpatterns as product_urls

urlpatterns = [

    url(r'^$', core_views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^products/', include(product_urls)),
    # url(r'^login/$', auth_views.login, name='login'),
    url(r'^login/$', auth_views.login, {'template_name': 'dashboard/login.html'}, name='login'),
    url(r'^logout/$', auth_views.logout, {'next_page': '/'}, name='logout'),
    # url(r'^logout/$', auth_views.logout, name='logout'),
    # url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
    url(r'^password_reset/$', auth_views.password_reset, {
        'post_reset_redirect': '/dashboard/password_reset/done/'
        , 'template_name': 'registration/password_reset_form.html'},
        name='password_reset'),
    url(r'^password_reset/done/$', auth_views.password_reset_done,
        {'template_name': 'registration/password_reset_done.html'}, name='password_reset_done'),

    url(r'^reset/(?P<uidb64>[0-9A-Za-z_\-]+)/(?P<token>[0-9A-Za-z]{1,13}-[0-9A-Za-z]{1,20})/$',
        auth_views.password_reset_confirm, {'template_name': 'registration/password_reset_confirm.html'},
        name='password_reset_confirm'),
    url(r'^reset/done/$', auth_views.password_reset_complete,
        {'template_name': 'registration/password_reset_complete.html'},
        name='password_reset_complete'),
]
```

error Traceback:

> File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/handlers.py",
>   line 66, in **call**
>
> return self.application(environ, start_response)
>
> File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py",
>   line 146, in **call**
>
> response = self.get_response(request)
>
> File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py",
>   line 81, in get_response
>
> response = self._middleware_chain(request)
>
> File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py",
>   line 37, in inner
>
> response = response_for_exception(request, exc)
>
> File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py",
>   line 87, in response_for_exception
>
> response = handle_uncaught_exception(request,
>   get_resolver(get_urlconf()), sys.exc_info())
>
> File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py",
>   line 122, in handle_uncaught_exception
>
> return debug.technical_500_response(request, *exc_info)
>
> File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django_extensions/management/technical_response.py", line 6, in null_technical_500_response
>
> six.reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/six.py", line 693, in
>   reraise
>
> raise value
>
> File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py",
>   line 35, in inner
>
> response = get_response(request)
>
> File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/deprecation.py",
>   line 95, in **call**
>
> response = self.get_response(request)
>
> File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py",
>   line 37, in inner
>
> response = response_for_exception(request, exc)
>
> File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py",
>   line 87, in response_for_exception
>
> response = handle_uncaught_exception(request,
>   get_resolver(get_urlconf()), sys.exc_info())
>
> File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py",
>   line 122, in handle_uncaught_exception
>
> return debug.technical_500_response(request, *exc_info)
>
> File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django_extensions/management/technical_response.py", line 6, in null_technical_500_response
>
> six.reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/six.py", line 693, in
>   reraise
>
> raise value
>
> File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py",
>   line 35, in inner
>
> response = get_response(request)
>
> File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/deprecation.py",
>   line 95, in **call**
>
> response = self.get_response(request)
>
> File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py",
>   line 37, in inner
>
> response = response_for_exception(request, exc)
>
> File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py",
>   line 87, in response_for_exception
>
> response = handle_uncaught_exception(request,
>   get_resolver(get_urlconf()), sys.exc_info())
>
> File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py",
>   line 122, in handle_uncaught_exception
>
> return debug.technical_500_response(request, *exc_info)
>
> File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django_extensions/management/technical_response.py", line 6, in null_technical_500_response
>
> six.reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/six.py", line 693, in
>   reraise
>
> raise value
>
> File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py",
>   line 35, in inner
>
> response = get_response(request)
>
> File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/deprecation.py",
>   line 95, in **call**
>
> response = self.get_response(request)
>
> File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py",
>   line 37, in inner
>
> response = response_for_exception(request, exc)
>
> File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py",
>   line 87, in response_for_exception
>
> response = handle_uncaught_exception(request,
>   get_resolver(get_urlconf()), sys.exc_info())
>
> File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py",
>   line 122, in handle_uncaught_exception
>
> return debug.technical_500_response(request, *exc_info)
>
> File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django_extensions/management/technical_response.py", line 6, in null_technical_500_response
>
> six.reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/six.py", line 693, in
>   reraise
>
> raise value
>
> File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py",
>   line 35, in inner
>
> response = get_response(request)
>
> File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/deprecation.py",
>   line 95, in **call**
>
> response = self.get_response(request)
>
> File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py",
>   line 37, in inner
>
> response = response_for_exception(request, exc)
>
> File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py",
>   line 87, in response_for_exception
>
> response = handle_uncaught_exception(request,
>   get_resolver(get_urlconf()), sys.exc_info())
>
> File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py",
>   line 122, in handle_uncaught_exception
>
> return debug.technical_500_response(request, *exc_info)
>
> File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django_extensions/management/technical_response.py", line 6, in null_technical_500_response
>
> six.reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/six.py", line 693, in
>   reraise
>
> raise value
>
> File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py",
>   line 35, in inner
>
> response = get_response(request)
>
> File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/deprecation.py",
>   line 95, in **call**
>
> response = self.get_response(request)
>
> File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py",
>   line 37, in inner
>
> response = response_for_exception(request, exc)
>
> File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py",
>   line 87, in response_for_exception
>
> response = handle_uncaught_exception(request,
>   get_resolver(get_urlconf()), sys.exc_info())
>
> File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py",
>   line 122, in handle_uncaught_exception
>
> return debug.technical_500_response(request, *exc_info)
>
> File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django_extensions/management/technical_response.py", line 6, in null_technical_500_response
>
> six.reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/six.py", line 693, in
>   reraise
>
> raise value
>
> File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py",
>   line 35, in inner
>
> response = get_response(request)
>
> File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/deprecation.py",
>   line 95, in **call**
>
> response = self.get_response(request)
>
> File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py",
>   line 37, in inner
>
> response = response_for_exception(request, exc)
>
> File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py",
>   line 87, in response_for_exception
>
> response = handle_uncaught_exception(request,
>   get_resolver(get_urlconf()), sys.exc_info())
>
> File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py",
>   line 122, in handle_uncaught_exception
>
> return debug.technical_500_response(request, *exc_info)
>
> File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django_extensions/management/technical_response.py", line 6, in null_technical_500_response
>
> six.reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/six.py", line 693, in
>   reraise
>
> raise value
>
> File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py",
>   line 35, in inner
>
> response = get_response(request)
>
> File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/deprecation.py",
>   line 95, in **call**
>
> response = self.get_response(request)
>
> File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py",
>   line 37, in inner
>
> response = response_for_exception(request, exc)
>
> File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py",
>   line 87, in response_for_exception
>
> response = handle_uncaught_exception(request,
>   get_resolver(get_urlconf()), sys.exc_info())
>
> File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py",
>   line 122, in handle_uncaught_exception
>
> return debug.technical_500_response(request, *exc_info)
>
> File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django_extensions/management/technical_response.py", line 6, in null_technical_500_response
>
> six.reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/six.py", line 693, in
>   reraise
>
> raise value
>
> File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py",
>   line 35, in inner
>
> response = get_response(request)
>
> File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/deprecation.py",
>   line 95, in **call**
>
> response = self.get_response(request)
>
> File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py",
>   line 37, in inner
>
> response = response_for_exception(request, exc)
>
> File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py",
>   line 87, in response_for_exception
>
> response = handle_uncaught_exception(request,
>   get_resolver(get_urlconf()), sys.exc_info())
>
> File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py",
>   line 122, in handle_uncaught_exception
>
> return debug.technical_500_response(request, *exc_info)
>
> File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django_extensions/management/technical_response.py", line 6, in null_technical_500_response
>
> six.reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/six.py", line 693, in
>   reraise
>
> raise value
>
> File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py",
>   line 35, in inner
>
> response = get_response(request)
>
> File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py",
>   line 128, in _get_response
>
> response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
>
> File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py",
>   line 126, in _get_response
>
> response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args,
>   **callback_kwargs)
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/contextlib.py", line 52, in inner
>
> return func(*args, **kwds)
>
> File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py",
>   line 69, in view
>
> return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
>
> File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py",
>   line 62, in _wrapper
>
> return bound_func(*args, **kwargs)
>
> File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py",
>   line 142, in _wrapped_view
>
> response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
>
> File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py",
>   line 58, in bound_func
>
> return func.**get**(self, type(self))(*args2, **kwargs2)
>
> File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/views.py",
>   line 407, in dispatch
>
> return super().dispatch(*args, **kwargs)
>
> File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py",
>   line 89, in dispatch
>
> return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
>
> File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/generic/edit.py",
>   line 142, in post
>
> return self.form_valid(form)
>
> File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/views.py",
>   line 420, in form_valid
>
> form.save(**opts)
>
> File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/forms.py",
>   line 297, in save
>
> email, html_email_template_name=html_email_template_name,
>
> File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/forms.py",
>   line 244, in send_mail
>
> body = loader.render_to_string(email_template_name, context)
>
> File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/loader.py",
>   line 62, in render_to_string
>
> return template.render(context, request)
>
> File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py",
>   line 61, in render
>
> return self.template.render(context)
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py",
>   line 175, in render
>
> return self._render(context)
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/test/utils.py",
>   line 98, in instrumented_test_render
>
> return self.nodelist.render(context)
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py",
>   line 943, in render
>
> bit = node.render_annotated(context)
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py",
>   line 910, in render_annotated
>
> return self.render(context)
>
> File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py",
>   line 37, in render
>
> output = self.nodelist.render(context)
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py",
>   line 943, in render
>
> bit = node.render_annotated(context)
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py",
>   line 910, in render_annotated
>
> return self.render(context)
>
> File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py",
>   line 447, in render
>
> url = reverse(view_name, args=args, kwargs=kwargs,
>   current_app=current_app)
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/urls/base.py",
>   line 88, in reverse
>
> return iri_to_uri(resolver._reverse_with_prefix(view, prefix, *args,
>   **kwargs))
>
> File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py",
>   line 632, in _reverse_with_prefix

Comment: Post whole error message with traceback. Also post your main urls.py and the template that causes the exception.

Comment: @Selcuk Does this help??

Comment: when this error occur?

Comment: @seuling: It occurs after I enter email for sending the password reset link

Comment: I think @kristaps wrote right answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're specifying a namespace - "dashboard" for the URLs you're including:

```
include(("ami.dashboard.urls", "dashboard"), namespace="dashboard"),
```

In this situation you need to include the namespace when reversing an URL, try:

```
reverse('dashboard:password_reset_confirm')
```

And in templates you would use:

```
{% url 'dashboard:password_reset_confirm' %}
```

More information in the Django docs: [Reversing namespaced URLs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/http/urls/#reversing-namespaced-urls)

Comment: Thanks I was using {% url  'password_reset_confirm' %} in my template